# AngularJS using a function in ng-class to conditionally set classes

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ng-class

i'm implementing a rating feature in my ionic app. i created icon fonts so i could display the the stars as classes.
I want to use the ngclass directive to conditionally set what the class is based on the rating.

for my question: Is my Logic and Syntax correct??

/* MODEL */

```
$scope.items = [{id: 1, name: 'foo', rating: 3 },{id: 2, name:'bar', rating: 4}]
```

...

/* CONTROLLER */

```
$scope.checkRating = function(rating) {

         if (rating === 1){ return 'one-star' }
    else if (rating === 2){ return 'two-star' }
    else if (rating === 3){ return 'three-star' }
    else if (rating === 4){ return 'four-star' }
    else if (rating === 5){ return 'five-star' }        

}
```

...

/* VIEW */

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item ng-repeat="item in items">
    <h2>{{item.name}}</h2>
    <p><span ng-class="checkRating(item.rating)"></span><p>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Comment: if it works it works. I know that seems like a useless answer, but to me this looks like it would work

Comment: thanks.. @SirNeuman i'm an angular newbie so i'm always unsure :)

Comment: Than check AngularJS Tutorial: A Comprehensive 10,000 Word Guide from my updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pankajparkar's answer is good but please consider following Angular JS best practices and avoid `$scope` syntax. Instead use [`controllerAs`](http://www.johnpapa.net/do-you-like-your-angular-controllers-with-or-without-sugar/).

Also, [John Papa's style guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide) is a very good source of good practices and you can learn much from it.

If you are new to AngularJS than I also recommend you to read [AngularJS Tutorial: A Comprehensive 10,000 Word Guide](https://www.airpair.com/angularjs/posts/angularjs-tutorial) by Todd Motto ‒ really worth to read.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than making conditional logic, I'd prefer to add class in `JSON`

**Markup**

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item ng-repeat="item in items">
    <h2>{{item.name}}</h2>
    <p><span ng-class="item.class"></span><p>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

**Code**

```
$scope.items = [{id: 1, name: 'foo', rating: 3, class: 'one-star' },
              {id: 2, name:'bar', rating: 4, class: 'two-star'}] ;
```

**OR**

Create a array with having the mapping of rating and ids and use it on html.

**HTML**

```
<p><span ng-class="$scope.ratings[item.rating]"></span><p>
```

**Markup**

```
$scope.ratings = {
    "1":'one-star',
    "2":'two-star',
    "3":'three-star',
    "4":'four-star',
    "5":'five-star'  
}
```

Comment: thanks, but i'll pull up the data from a rest api.. but i get your point

Comment: @teddybear123 are you looking for something more...I think its better to accept one of our answer..what are you waiting for?